# Add a median "best fit line" to a scatter plot in r

Tags: r, curve-fitting, scatter-plot

I would like to add an empirical line of best fit to a scatter plot that is based on the median y for a range of x, eg at x=0.105 would be the y line of the median y's for x in the range 0.100 to 0.110, at x=0.115 would be the y line of the median y's for x in the range 0.110 to 0.120, etc. These y line points will be joined up. These x's are just for illustration, I'd like to be flexible in their choice. (I do not want a parametric fit, thanks)

This simulates some data:

```
x<-0.1+runif(n=1000,min=0,max=1)
y<-1/x+runif(n=1000,min=0,max=1)*(1-x)*5
plot(x,y)
```

Here is a mock up of the median line in orange.

[image: mock up of desired plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into the lowess smoothing as option. Look into the f option on how 'smooth' you would like it to be. I copied some documentation below.

> option f   the smoother span. This gives the proportion of points in
>   the plot which influence the smooth at each value. Larger values give
>   more smoothness.

```
x<-0.1+runif(n=1000,min=0,max=1)
    y<-1/x+runif(n=1000,min=0,max=1)*(1-x)*5    
    plot(x, y)
    lines(lowess(x, y), col=2)
    lines(lowess(x, y, f=.2), col=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

After your `plot()` function, try the following:

```
lines( x = lowess( x = x, y = y ), col = "darkgoldenrod2", lwd = 4 )
```

From [`?lowess`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lowess.html):

> `lowess` returns a list containing components x and y which give the coordinates of the smooth. The smooth can be added to a plot of the original points with the function [`lines()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/lines.html).